# Is it possible to move webpack-dev-server default context

Tags: reactjs, webpack

If I start my webpack-dev-server it listens for my application on localhost:8080/. I want now move the context for application from '/' to '/test'. Is there any way to do this?

Every help is welcome.

My part of package.json to start webpack-dev-server

```
 "devserver": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --inline --hot --config webpack.config.devel.js --content-base public/"
```

Comment: R u using react router ?? Because by router u can achieve this easily.

Comment: Yes, but but Ich want move more global

Comment: I want use this dir easier proxy configuration

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with webpack config. Tho original configuration looks like

```
...
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [
        './src/index.tsx'
    ],
    output:  {
        path:       path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
        filename:   'my_app.js',
        publicPath: '/dist'
},
...
```

After change the publicPath attrib the application is accessible with context '/test'

```
output:  {
    path:       path.join(__dirname, 'public/test'),
    filename:   'my_app.js',
    publicPath: '/test/'
},
```